# How do I add a label for the y-axis in Datadog?

Tags: python, datadog

I have a chart for a custom metric like this one:

[image]

How can I add a label for the y-axis? I don't see any option in the dashboard settings. Exploring other metrics, I see they already have such label. For example, `kubernetes.cpu.usage.total` shows `millicores`, independently of the dashboard:

[image]

So, I guess that maybe I need to send the metric with some metadata already? I can't find any information about this.

FWIW, I'm using the Datadog's Python client to submit the metric: `api.Metric.send(metric='custom.foo', points=(now, point))`

Comment: Hey! Did you ever find a way of adding a label for the y-axis?

Comment: It's odd... the [widget API says](https://docs.datadoghq.com/dashboards/widgets/timeseries/) that there "yaxis" property has a "label" property, which sounds like it should work, but I can't get it to show up.

Comment: hey @MichaelF, I had answered the question in the past but the community decided that it wasn't a proper answer and hid it. Go to this linkhttps://docs.datadoghq.com/metrics/units/, all the necessary information is there.